# Understanding "this" within anonymous function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, anonymous-function

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), lots of answers are there discussing the `this` keyword in JavaScript. However, I am still confuse `this` in the `anonymous function` as following

```
// MyModule.js
'use strict';
(function(handler) {
    // export methods
    handler.B = B;
    handler.A = A;

    function A() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log('function A is invoked...');
    }

    function B() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log('function B is invoked...');
        try {
            A();
            this.A();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Exception is ' + err);
        }
    }
})(module.exports);

// test.js
var myModule = require('MyModule.js');
myModule.B();
```

Output: (Running under Node.js)

```
{ B: [Function: B], A: [Function: A] }
function B is invoked...

undefined
function A is invoked...

{ B: [Function: B], A: [Function: A] }
function A is invoked...
```

The output indicates the function `A` are in two different scopes. Am I right? Why there are two scopes for function `A`?

As we know, the `this` is related to the scope. And the `this` in the anonymous function of `MyModule` is `undefined`. According to the output, one of the scope of function `A` is `undefined`, the other is `{ B: [Function: B], A: [Function: A] }`. What the difference between them?

Comment: not two different scopes, two different context, not the same `this`.

Comment: On a sitenote, "use strict" should be inside your anonymous function.

Comment: @koningdavid: It's fine where it is as well, if you don't need to use `this` at global scope to get at the global object, which the code above doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

`this` and scope have almost nothing to do with each other. In JavaScript, `this` is usually set by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined. (There are two exceptions to that rule, I'll mention them below.)

So when you're calling `A`, you're setting what `this` will be during the call (largely implicitly). When you do this:

```
A();
```

...you're calling `A` without doing anything explicit to set what `this` should be; as a result, you're implicitly calling it with `this` set to `undefined`, because your code is in strict mode. (If it were in loose mode, you'd be calling it with `this` set to a reference to the global object.) It's also worth noting that you're resolving the identifier `A` via the context created by the call to your anonymous function, which contains `A` and `B` as (effectively) variables.

But here:

```
this.A();
```

...you're calling `A` as part of an expression getting the function reference from an object property (`A`; note that this is a *different* meaning for `A`, but that both the property and the context variable refer to the same function). The act of doing that calls `A` with `this` set to a reference to the object you got the property from.

That's why you see two different values for `this` in `A`.

The exceptions to the "`this` is set by how you call it" rule are:

1. ES6's "arrow" functions, which inherit `this` from the *context* (not scope) where they're created.
2. ES5's "bound" functions (the result of calling `.bind` on a function reference), which have `this` baked into them by the `.bind` call and so always see the same value for `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `this`, in a function, is bound to the object on which you called that function.

In your example:

- You call `myModule.B()`, `this` equals to `myModule`, as you can see from the output: `{ B: [Function: B], A: [Function: A] }`
- Then, inside the `try` block you call `A()` without an object, here `this` is `undefined` because you're running **in strict mode**, otherwise it would point to the **global object**, which is `window` in a browser or `global` in node
- Finally, the last call is `this.A()`, here you're basically passing your current `this` (`myModule`) to the function, so it will be `myModule`.

The whole `this` binding is affected only by the way you call a function.