# How to access the property from method defined in the same object javascript

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I have defined a function which returns object which has property and a method. using the returned object I am calling the method inside the object to get the value of the property in the object. but I didn't received what I expected.

```
function test(){

    return {
        a:'test property',
        fn:()=>{
             console.log('property', this.a);
        }
    }

}

 const obj = test();
 obj.fn() // what I expect is test property but I received undefined.
```

[image]

Comment: the anonymous function passes `this` within the scope of `test()`. You need to use a named function. See: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or [Understanding “this” within anonymous function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651685/understanding-this-within-anonymous-function-in-javascript)

Comment: See also [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding "this" within anonymous function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651685/understanding-this-within-anonymous-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You have declared the function incorrectly. Remember that arrow functions do not have their own `this` like a regular function does.

You should declare it like this:

```js
function test() {
  return {
    a: 'test property',
    fn() {
      console.log('property', this.a);
    },
  };
}
const obj = test();
obj.fn();
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the difference between the both function. I am assigning a function to a fn key but you are defining a function in a object. At the end the function fn going to be called why it behaves different

Comment: arrow functions do not have their own "this" as regular functions

Answer (score 1):

When you use a regular function `this` is scoped to how it is called. example

```
obj.fn()
```

`obj` is taken as your `this`

when you define using arrow function `this` is assigned on creation which points to the parent's context in your case its `window`